# Compose not working with Dockerfile using FROM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Right now, I am using a docker-compose file that contains, amongst other stuff, a few lines like this. This executes without any sort of problem. It deploys perfectly and I'm able to access the web server inside through the browser.

```
  container:
    command: bash -c "cd /code; chmod +x ./deploy/start_dev.sh; ./deploy/start_dev.sh;"
    image: python:3.6
```

As I needed to be able to connect to the container through SSH I created a Dockerfile that installs it and modifies the config file so it allows unsafe root connections:

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server -y
RUN sed -i "s/PermitRootLogin without-password/PermitRootLogin yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN sed -i "s/PermitEmptyPasswords no/PermitEmptyPasswords yes/g" /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN service ssh restart
RUN echo "root:sshpassword" | chpasswd

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

After that I changed the docker-compose file to:

```
container:
    command: bash -c "cd /code; chmod +x ./deploy/start_dev.sh; ./deploy/start_dev.sh;"
    build:
        context: .
```

From this moment on, whenever I run *docker-compose up* I get the following output:

```
container exited with code 0
```

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it switching the last two lines of the Dockerfile

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

to

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/bin/bash"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `docker-compose.yaml` file, add the following parameter (under the 'container' section):

```
tty: true
```

Comment: I solved it before reading your answer, though it took me a while. Thank you anyways!